# Best way to concurrently replace data in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

We store our analytics data of video playback in sessionStorage.

The form of data is as fallow:

```ts
interface IplayerPlayed {
    [fileID: string]: {
        /** Non-overlapping time ranges */
        tracks: number[][]
        /** Some value of last threshold passed */
        passed?: number | string
    }
}
```

Problem is, that we need to be able to save data even if user plays two videos at once.

What I did initially.

```
const playerPlayed = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('PLAYER_played_analytics') || '{}');
const currentAnalytics = playerPlayed[fileID] || (playerPlayed[fileID] = { tracks: [] })

// some code...

sessionStorage.setItem('PLAYER_played_analytics', JSON.stringify(playerPlayed));
```

This is not working, when two or more videos are playing in multiple tabs as it will override new data from other tab with data it parsed initially.

Possible solutions:

- Parse before every save. (This is definitively safest, but also pretty slow)
- Use regExp to find in string and replace it without parsing JSON.

---

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pretty slow"? Have you tried it? How humongous is your data?

Comment: @Bergi This parsing occurs quite often (about 3x second), and `JSON.parse` is known to be slow.

Comment: 3/s isn't that often, and where did you get the notion that `JSON.parse` is slow?

Comment: Of course, if you really think that parsing is too slow, you could simply remember the json string and compare it, so that you only have to parse when the session storage content changed.

Comment: @Bergi Comparing seems like interesting idea, indeed. Thought for now I settled on splitting it to multiple keys and parsing, as now it is way smaller, so it shouldn't be that bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was writing last words of this question, I found the prefect answer. Use `fileID`s in sessisionStorage keys, as such, this will only occur if user is playing same video twice in two tabs, which is unlikely and acceptable.

Example (simplified):

```
const currentAnalytics = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(`PLAYER_${fileID}_analytics`) || { tracks: [] }

// some code...

sessionStorage.setItem(`PLAYER_${fileID}_analytics`, JSON.stringify(currentAnalytics ));
```

For anyone, feel free to suggest better solution as this is not yet perfect.